# How to change the date in pandas datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to change the date of pandas column with time having seconds in float format to make certain date. But, I was not able to make it work.

My attempt so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1.0,2.0,3.0,60.0,120.1,120.2]})


df['date'] = '2013-09-01 00:00:' + df['time'].astype(str)
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%-S') # this fails

df
```

Reference: http://strftime.org/

I could not find the string format for my time. How to solve the problem.
I appreciate the help.

## Question

By default pandas gives 1970 january 1 as date, how to make it 2013 Sep 1 ?

## update

I also tried this

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime('2013-09-01')
df['date3'] = df['date'].dt + df['date2'].dt
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Do you want to change the time with respect to delta in seconds?

Comment: @khan yes, i would like to do that.

Comment: @BhishanPoudel your update thrown some light for me to explore and find the answer, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use direct `to_timedelta` to add with `to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime('2013-09-01') + pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='s')

Out[19]:
0   2013-09-01 00:00:01.000
1   2013-09-01 00:00:02.000
2   2013-09-01 00:00:03.000
3   2013-09-01 00:01:00.000
4   2013-09-01 00:02:00.100
5   2013-09-01 00:02:00.200
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, you should create a `date` column first and parse it as a default datetime and then find the delta.

You can use Python's `datetime` library for this job:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1.0,2.0,3.0,60.0,120.1,120.2]})
df['date'] = datetime.strptime('2013-09-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['date2'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.date - timedelta(seconds=row.time), axis=1)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas Timedelta for this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1.0,2.0,3.0,60.0,120.1,120.2]})


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2013-09-01') + pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(t, unit='s') for t in df['time']])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    time                    date
0    1.0 2013-09-01 00:00:01.000
1    2.0 2013-09-01 00:00:02.000
2    3.0 2013-09-01 00:00:03.000
3   60.0 2013-09-01 00:01:00.000
4  120.1 2013-09-01 00:02:00.100
5  120.2 2013-09-01 00:02:00.200
```

For more references visit: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html